# How to use LaunchPad and Mission Control on Mountain Lion with an external keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, mission-control, launchpad, expose

I am using an external (generic) keyboard.

I just switched from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion.

On Snow Leopard, I could pull up Expose by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> on my external keyboard, but now I can't.

Is there a FN key (or a way to enable the right FN key) to show "Mission Control"?

Comment: Is "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" unchecked in the keyboard preferences?

Answer (score 1):

Open System Preferences and click on "Mission Control". You'll see the keyboard shortcuts for expose and mission control at the bottom of this panel.

For other keyboard shortcuts you can open the keyboard panel and then click on "keyboard shortcuts"

Answer (score 0):

By default, <kbd>F9</kbd> launches Mission Control on an external, third-party keyboard in Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one of the new Apple keyboards - The Launchpad button is <kbd>F4</kbd>, and Mission Control is <kbd>F3</kbd> (At least on the US keyboards)